# Does not render the view after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

When i run the Logout function and goes to /logout i want to set my user to null and render a logout page but this code just set null and does not render anything that i wrote in return what is the problem?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";

    const Logout = () => {
      const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    
      dispatch({
        type: "SET_USER",
        user: null,
      });
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h1
            style={{
              "background-color": "#F3B858",
              height: "100%",
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
              height: "90vh",
              color: "#fff",
              "font-size": "80px",
              "font-weight": 900,
            }}
          >
            BYE
          </h1>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Logout;
```

StateProvider:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

Comment: Can you share your StateProvider.js

Comment: I added it. @SinanYaman

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
useEffect(() => {
dispatch({
        type: "SET_USER",
        user: null,
      });
},[user])
```

Comment: still same. It does not render the view

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this approach before. It was my only guess. I hope you will find the solution soon